Young adult horror story in which a boy's neighbor turns out to be the Devil
What I can remember is that a boy lives with his grandma in a apartment and a new neighbor moves in. The kid befriends the neighbor as the neighbor seems to know the kid's secret thoughts. It turns out that the  neighbor is the Devil and can hear through walls. He tries to make the kid do something bad and take his soul, but gets trapped somehow using a key shop.

In roughly which year did you read this? And was it a short story? If so, did you read it in an anthology, a magazine, or online?
